# .cameraPosition.target does not provide center of current view

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a location marked in google map. The user has the option to change this location by dragging the map. I am using camera position to get the new location.Here is my code to get the original location:

```
mMap = googleMap    
val addkey = intent.getStringExtra("address")
var addlocation = getLocationFromAddress(addkey) as LatLng
var mapLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(addlocation, 18.0f)
mMap.animateCamera(mapLocation)
```

The getLocationFromAddress code is working fine.

The user then drags to a new location, clicks a button when done and upon confirmation the new location is accepted. I am trying to get the Latitude Longitude of the current camera position using the single line code:

```
addlocation = mMap.cameraPosition.target
```

But the code continues to return the Lat Long of old view. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Implement it like this -

```
private GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener;
```

then use the camera listener to get the latitude longitude from the camera center position like this -

```
onCameraIdleListener = new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {

                LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);

                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        String locality = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        if (!locality.isEmpty() && !country.isEmpty())
                            resutText.setText(locality + "  " + country);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
```

Getting the address is an addition thing added here. Use it if you need it.